# What to do when there's nothing to return in a promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

When I have a promise, I usually do something like:

```
funcPromise()
.then(()=> {
    // some stuff happens
    return value; // what if there's nothing to return here?
})
.then(()=> { //... 
})
.catch(err=>log(err));
```

But if there's nothing to return, should i do `return Promise.resolve()` or `return null`, or simply `return;`?? I know that in a one-liner, the arrow function has implicit return, but for my case, it's a multi-statement function.

Comment: A function that doesn't `return` anything will produce `undefined`. No extra provisions necessary.

Comment: What does `funcPromise()` do that does not have any result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

If you have no `return` statement (or a `return` statement with no value), the function will return `undefined`, resulting in a promise of `undefined`.

That is presumably fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

The promise actually returns an object that has a value if you call the right method. Maybe that helps?